# When I see Mars, I see only red light

Tags: observational-astronomy, solar-system, photography, mars, night-sky

I have a 700 mm focal and 76 mm aperture telescope. I bought it a few days ago. I tried to spot Mars for 3 days but I only see red light. I use an 20 mm eyepiece for finding it and 4 mm eyepiece for seeing but only red light is visible. Please help me.

Comment: Is the red light just a dot or a ring of red light?
EDIT : If you could also link to your telescope model, it would be great.

Comment: If you go to [astronomy.tools' FoV calculator](http://astronomy.tools/calculators/field_of_view/), select Mars from the "Solar system" dropdown, then enter in your telescope and eyepiece details, and click "Add to view"; does the resulting image look like what you can see?

Comment: As RyugaGod asked, is it a dot/disk or a ring?  'Cause my first thought is you're out of focus, and a ring would be very indicative of that.  Also, I assume you DON'T have a filter on there that's red?  (I've left filters on my camera that I forgot about.)

Answer (score 1):

Mmm... it's a pretty small scope using a fairly high power. The disc of Mars is not going to be very large (just a few seconds of arc across) so I don't think you should expect to see something that looks like a HST image! Mars is pretty red as a rule, so 'red light' is what you should be seeing because the disc is too small to show much detail.